# How to play audio specific time in wordpress / javascript, such as 60s

Tags: javascript, wordpress, audio

i want to make a audio online shop. 
there i sell audio. so, i upload main music there.
i make a restiction for user. 
User can play only 60s then audio stop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Audio time set to zero</title>
</head>

<body>
  <audio id="myaudio" src="5 yr Plan - 140Bpm_Fm.mp3"></audio>
  <button onclick="settime()">play</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function settime() {
      var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      audio.play();
      console.log(audio.currentTime);
      setInterval(function() {
        if (audio.currentTime > 60) {
          audio.pause();
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and, what is the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: reset `audio.currentTime`  to `0` once reached `60`

Comment: when i used the code, it work for only one audio. other audio is play ...

Comment: Well, of course, since you're getting audio element by **ID** `getElementById("myaudio")` and there can only be ONE audio with ID=myaudio - besides, the code you posted only has one audio element - perhaps you need to show the code you are actually having an issue with

Comment: use common class, get them to iterate and update

Comment: i want to change it for dynamicly all audio ....
i find a better solution ...

Comment: `i find a better solution` - OK, so you don't need help anymore

Comment: sorry i want to find better solution.... for this

Comment: Oh, so you want a solution ... what's wrong with the code you wrote? If you want help for something other than the exact code you wrote, it will be difficult - please show code you have problem with

Comment: this code i used my project....
but no output client requirment

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Does you code play for 60 seconds then stop? Or does it do something wrong? There's not much wrong with your code

Comment: yes...
i don't want to use this code....
i want to find a better solution for this.
a audio play 60s then stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) event for listening `currentTime` property change and when it's reached `60` pause the audio.

```
<audio id="myaudio" src="5 yr Plan - 140Bpm_Fm.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="settime()">play</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function settime() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
      if(this.currentTime >= 60) this.pause()
    })
  }
</script>
```

**FYI :** If there are multiple audio tags then iterate and attach same event handler.